# Query condition on populated element possible?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

Can I do a where-condition on a populated field?

I can do a `find().where('p').equals(q._id)`
but not a `find().populate('p', 'element').where('p.element').equals(q.element)`

or what is the syntax for queries of this type?

Or isn't it possible in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the population as follows:

```
Story
.find(...)
.populate({
  path: 'fans',
  match: { age: { $gte: 21 }},
  select: 'name -_id',
  options: { limit: 5 }
})
.exec()
```

The above example was taken directly from mongoose documentation on this page:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, search for the heading **Query conditions and other options**

Comment: That does completely different thing. This only limits the populated items. So in this example you get all Stories but only populated with some fans. What I need is, that I only get Stories where a specific fan is in the populated documents.

Comment: The only way to get it to work is currently to lookup the _id of the fan and then use this _id as query condition without population. Ugly coding work. Would be nice if there is some built-in solution...

Comment: Ah sorry i completely mis-understood what you wanted. Yea i think the solution that you've got is the only way to do it really :/